# How to calculate the number of occurrences an attribute appear in a JSON array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have retrieved a JSON object from a public data API which look similar to following.

```
[
  {
    "category": "Burglary",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.497877",
      "street": {
        "id": 953834,
        "name": "On or near Major Road"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.064175"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832838,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  },
  {
    "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.497877",
      "street": {
        "id": 953834,
        "name": "On or near Major Road"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.064175"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832841,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  },
  {
    "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.497877",
      "street": {
        "id": 953834,
        "name": "On or near Major Road"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.064175"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832849,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  },
  {
    "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.500440",
      "street": {
        "id": 953881,
        "name": "On or near Chambers Street"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.066891"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832881,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  } ]
```

I am trying to count how many crimes happened in each category. Is it correct to access category value as 'obj[0].category' ? What would be the best way to count them?

Comment: Loop over and keep track of each category and increment them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've parsed the JSON to get an array of objects, you can use the [array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to count the categories. `.reduce()` calls the function that you pass it once for each item in your array, passing as arguments an "accumulator" `acc`, which in this case will be an object `{}`, and the current array value `crime`.

```
var data = // your data here
var categories = data.reduce(function(acc, crime) {
  if (!acc[crime.category])   // if current category not in acc object
    acc[crime.category] = 1;  // add it to acc with value 1
  else                        // otherwise (it exists), so
    acc[crime.category]++;    // increment it
  return acc;
}, {});
```

The result will be an object like this:

```
{
  "Burglary": 1,
  "anti-social-behaviour": 3
}
```

...so if you want to know how many burglaries occurred you could say `categories["Burglary"]`.

(Expand and run the following snippet to see it work...)

```js
var data = [
  {
    "category": "Burglary",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.497877",
      "street": {
        "id": 953834,
        "name": "On or near Major Road"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.064175"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832838,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  },
  {
    "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.497877",
      "street": {
        "id": 953834,
        "name": "On or near Major Road"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.064175"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832841,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  },
  {
    "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.497877",
      "street": {
        "id": 953834,
        "name": "On or near Major Road"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.064175"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832849,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  },
  {
    "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
    "location_type": "Force",
    "location": {
      "latitude": "51.500440",
      "street": {
        "id": 953881,
        "name": "On or near Chambers Street"
      },
      "longitude": "-0.066891"
    },
    "context": "",
    "outcome_status": null,
    "persistent_id": "",
    "id": 53832881,
    "location_subtype": "",
    "month": "2016-12"
  } ]

var categories = data.reduce(function(acc, crime) {
  if (!acc[crime.category])
    acc[crime.category] = 1;
  else
    acc[crime.category]++;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(categories);
console.log(categories["Burglary"]);
```

Note that [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Either you have JSON, which is a string representation/serialisation of your array/object, or you have an actual array or object.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, using `Array#forEach`.

```js
var json = [{category:"Burglary",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.497877",street:{id:953834,name:"On or near Major Road"},longitude:"-0.064175"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832838,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"},{category:"anti-social-behaviour",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.497877",street:{id:953834,name:"On or near Major Road"},longitude:"-0.064175"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832841,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"},{category:"anti-social-behaviour",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.497877",street:{id:953834,name:"On or near Major Road"},longitude:"-0.064175"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832849,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"},{category:"anti-social-behaviour",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.500440",street:{id:953881,name:"On or near Chambers Street"},longitude:"-0.066891"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832881,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"}], 
    result = {};
  
    json.forEach(function(v){
      !result[v.category] ? result[v.category] = 1 : result[v.category] += 1;
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce()` function:

```js
var data = [{category:"Burglary",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.497877",street:{id:953834,name:"On or near Major Road"},longitude:"-0.064175"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832838,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"},{category:"anti-social-behaviour",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.497877",street:{id:953834,name:"On or near Major Road"},longitude:"-0.064175"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832841,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"},{category:"anti-social-behaviour",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.497877",street:{id:953834,name:"On or near Major Road"},longitude:"-0.064175"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832849,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"},{category:"anti-social-behaviour",location_type:"Force",location:{latitude:"51.500440",street:{id:953881,name:"On or near Chambers Street"},longitude:"-0.066891"},context:"",outcome_status:null,persistent_id:"",id:53832881,location_subtype:"",month:"2016-12"}], 
   
    counts = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        (r[o.category])? r[o.category]++ : r[o.category] = 1;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce),

```
var arr = [{
  "category": "Burglary",
}, {
  "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
}, {
  "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
}, {
  "category": "anti-social-behaviour",
}];

var results = arr.reduce(function(result, itm){
    return (result[itm.category] = (result[itm.category] || 0) + 1, result);
}, {});

console.log(results); //Object {Burglary: 1, anti-social-behaviour: 3}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h171onf5/)